# Eliminar el número más alto y el número más bajo de un array en Javascript

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo este enunciado

Eliminar extremos. Ingresar mediante prompt números hasta el ingreso de un 0. Almacenar la información en un array. Eliminar del array el número más alto y el más bajo. (Si el más alto o bajo se repiten solo eliminarlos una vez).

Pero solo he conseguido llegar hasta aquí

```js
      let numeros = [];
        let ingresoUsuario;

        while (ingresoUsuario !== "0") {
            ingresoUsuario = prompt("Ingresa un numero");
            numeros.push(ingresoUsuario);            
        }

        let min = Math.min(...numeros);
        let max = Math.max(...numeros);

        

        console.log(numeros);
        console.log(min);
        console.log(max);
```

Comment: He probado la ejecución de tu código y funciona. (La única pega que le veo es que el 0 también lo añades a la lista y lo toma como el valor menor de la lista). No lo incluyas en la lista y lo tienes perfecto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript tiene las funciones [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/max)  y [`Math.min()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/min) para encontrar con facilidad el valor mayor o menor de un array.

Luego puedes buscar el índice de ese valor para borrarlo del array con [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/splice)

Aquí, para más versatilidad, he usado una función.

```js
let numeros = [1, 5, 4, 9, 0, -3, 9, 4, -3];

removeMinMax(numeros);
console.log(numeros);

function removeMinMax() {
  var min = Math.min(...numeros);
  var max = Math.max(...numeros);
  /*Remover cada valor por su índice*/
  numeros.splice(numeros.indexOf(min), 1);
  numeros.splice(numeros.indexOf(max), 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes probar a ordenar la lista de manera ascendente o descendente en caso de que quieras eliminar el elemento mayor o el menor (sort() -> https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort):

`let numeros = [1,8,3,25,14];
 numeros.sort(function(a,b){ return a - b }) // [1, 3, 8, 14, 25]
 numeros.sort(function(a,b){ return b - a }) // [25, 14, 8, 3, 1]`

Y finalmente puedes utilizar la función pop() (https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/pop) para eliminar el último elemento de la lista:

`numeros.sort(function(a,b){ return b - a }).pop() // [25, 14, 8, 3]`